# Does a Mailbox Export Request modify the mailbox data?

Tags: windows, forensics, exchange

The procedure suggested by forensics companies to make a copy of a users's mailbox in a forensically sound manner is to use [`New-MailboxExportRequest`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff459227%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx).

**What information is modified (if any) by the use of this command?**

My understanding is that the action is logged but was under the impression that the mailbox data themselves were not modified.

I would appreciate technical references if possible (I did not find any)

Answer (score 1):

Mailbox export request is the industry standard way to export data from Exchange for compliance, audit, and compliance purposes.

No data is modified, [BUT it is possible to](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607299(v=exchg.150).aspx) constrain the output to a certain date range, search for specific content, or include/exclude different folders.

If the archive parameter is set, then data will be removed from the mailbox.

Comment: I know that this is the command which is used - I was more looking for either references from forensics SOPs or technical information about the modifications (or lack of) this command does when run against a mailbox (and an Exchnage server)

Comment: @WoJ At a minimum, the server will log that an export was done in the Event log and a few other places